# what does int (*a)[10]

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Interpretation of int (*a)[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250397/interpretation-of-int-a3)
>   [What does “char (*a)[12]” mean ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011972/what-does-char-a12-mean)

i would really appreciate if you can explain with help of program

Comment: You don't really have a question here.  What is `int (*a)[10]` in your code?  What do you think it is—any ideas?  What's the context of the code?  Is there any particular reason you want to know?  And just so this comment is also somewhat helpful, when trying to decipher C type declarations, [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) is handy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810083/c-pointers-pointing-to-an-array-of-fixed-size

Comment: and another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011972/what-does-char-a12-mean

Answer (score 8):

It declares `a` as a pointer to an array of 10 ints.

Comment: http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/

Someone posted this in a different thread, it is a marvelous tool :)